# Do all 12V batteries produce the same amount of current?

Tags: battery, battery-drain

I have a car battery which is roughly 12 V. Sometimes, I will not use the car for a week (I bike instead), and the battery voltage drops to 9.5 V ~ 10 V. This low voltage makes it hard to start the car.

Can I use another 12 V battery which is physically much smaller than the car battery to start it?

Comment: The answer to the title is no. But google "jump start battery". These are portable emergency start batteries, exactly designed for this purpose.

Comment: It would be  great if i know, Why 12v batteries produce different currents. When the same 12v batteries are connected in a circuit with ~ zero resistance. then they should produce same current right ???

Comment: Because current x voltage x time = energy. You can't "pack" enough energy inside a small volume. Theoretically it could provide a high current, but for a very short time.

Comment: wow Thank you so much Eugene Sh. You answer was simple to understand

Comment: Not really answering your question, but if your car battery voltage sinks to 9.5 after a week, it's toast and you should get a replacement, or your cars electrical system has other problems and is draining it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer - No.

Different types of battery have different maximum currents they can supply. This is limited by their 'internal resistance.'

The voltage rating of a battery does not signify the current it is capable of supplying under different conditions.

e.g.

**Cold cranking amps (CCA):**

CCA is a rating used in the battery industry to define a battery's ability to start an engine in cold temperatures. Generally speaking, it is easier to start an engine in a warm environment than in a cold environment. The rating refers to the number of amps a 12-volt battery can deliver at 0°F for 30 seconds while maintaining a voltage of at least 7.2 volts. The higher the CCA rating, the greater the starting power of the battery.

**Reserve capacity (RC):**

RC is a general indicator of how long a new, fully charged battery can continue to operate essential accessories if the vehicle’s alternator fails. It identifies how many minutes the battery can deliver a constant current of 25 amps at 80°F without falling below the minimum voltage, 1.75 volts per cell, needed to keep your vehicle running.

**C20 capacity**:

Some premium batteries also define their C20 capacity in ampere-hour (Ah). C20 capacity is an indicator of how much energy is stored in a battery. It is the energy a battery can deliver continuously for 20 hours at 80°F without falling below 10.5 volts.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. The small portable starter units have something like a 12V 22ah sealed lead-acid (SLA) battery inside. The battery has to be able to supply a lot of current to crank the engine, so many similar-sounding batteries are unsuitable for the task.

But if your car battery is dying in a week, it's either on its last legs or there is something (a load that is not switched) draining it. I suggest you figure out what is going on and fix it. You should be able to leave the car for a month or two without problems. A new car battery is not much more expensive than a small SLA battery (just heavier). You can also get float chargers that maintain the battery- typically used by folks in cold climates who park a summer car over the winter and need to be able to start it in the spring after months in storage.

Comment: Thanks for answering.It would be great if i know, Why 12v batteries produce different currents. When the same 12v batteries are connected in a circuit with ~ zero resistance. then they should produce same current right ???

Comment: All batteries have some internal resistance (which varies with temperature, battery condition and charge state). On car batteries you can find a specification "Cold Cranking Amps" that tells you how a lot about the battery's ability to supply current. High current capacity requires different internal construction.

Comment: Those small units are also only capable of starting the car if the car's battery still has a good amount of juice, but just not able to finish the job.

Comment: @whatsisname They can do it, even with the car battery removed, if the temperature is not cold and the car fires up smartly. A surprising amount of current capability.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your other question, why do some lead acid batteries provide higher current than others?

It has to do with the manufacturing process. High current lead acid batteries are built with thinner, higher surface area lead plates, while the higher capacity deep cycle batteries use thicker plates.  They both are 12 volts but provide different services.